# Is there a name for objects all of whose endomorphisms are automorphisms?

Tags: ct.category-theory, galois-theory, automorphism-groups, groupoids, universal-property

I am looking for a descriptive adjective to describe the following special property that some objects in some categories enjoy: their endomorphism monoids are groups. Of course, one way this could happen is if the ambient category is a groupoid, but in the cases I am interested in, the objects in question do receive and emit noninvertible morphisms; only their endomorphisms are invertible. For example, in the category of commutative rings, polynomial rings do not enjoy this property, but (if I'm not mistaken) <strike>fields of finite transcendence degree do</strike>.

Any suggestions on a term to use?

Comment: This makes me think of 'rigid', but I guess that, as usually understood, that is the related (?) but distinct property that the only automorphism is the identity.

Comment: This is sometimes called "coalescence" in dynamical systems. The term is used in the measured context here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.00341 and in the topological context here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2647

Comment: Since in the abelian context the role of such is played by simple objects - all of their *nonzero* endomorphisms are automorphisms - maybe call these simple too?

Comment: Categories in which all objects have that property are sometimes called EI-categories. They are, in a way, the marriage of groupoids with posets.

Comment: Fields of finite transcendence degree enjoy what? the endomorphism of $\mathbf{Q}(t)$ mapping $P(t)$ to $P(t^2)$ is not invertible.

Comment: @LSpice: **rigid** means (to me) that it has **no automorphisms** (probably no endomorphisms, but in the example I have in mind, all morphisms are mono anyway).  How about **corporeal**, as a nod to the example of fields.  I'm assuming this word hasn't been used before in category theory.) Another idea: **incompressible**.

Comment: @YCor Oops, wasn't thinking straight.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I would interpret "incompressible" to mean that any morphism emitted by the object is a monomorphism. Or maybe (more strongly) every morphism emitted is an injection, which makes sense if my category is concrete (= consists of sets+structure).

Comment: Not sure this is helpful, but you can split this into "every endomorphism is epic" and "every epic endo is auto", and the latter is/could be called "Hopfian".

Comment: Often "coalescence" in topological dynamical systems is discussed in the context of minimal systems, where trivially every endomorphism is epic.

Comment: You need some more concrete examples to suggest a suitable name.  The one I'm thinking of is sets ($\in$-structures) considered as extensional well founded $\mathcal P$-coalgebras, for which see section 7 of (http://www.paultaylor.eu/ordinals/welfcr.pdf)

Comment: As pointed out by Tilman, it is pretty common to use EI-category to mean every Endomorphism in a category is Invertible.  I am not sure if category theorists use this but people doing representations and cohomology of categories do and  it is fairly widely used now.  So I think EI-object would be reasonable. The EI-objects give the largest full subcategory which is an EI-category and the Endomorphism is Invertible acronym still makes sense.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I completely agree. In categories of spaces, this condition typically only holds for points. So I was tempted by something like "pointal"...

Comment: If "Ei" is the German word, then every endomorphism is indeed either an isomorphism or a zero!